# SAPUi5 dropdownbox select event

Tags: sapui5

We have used dropdownbox.

```
var r1c1 = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("r1c1");

r1c1.addEventDelegate({
    onselect : function(oEvent) {

}
});
```

The breakpoint is not stopping at this, it was working fine, We have put logic based on onselect event.  Is someone facing the same issue,

Even in browser, i have put Event listener select event, it is not getting stopped for that also.

Best regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

```
var r1c1 = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
    change: yourFunction
})
```